# How to make cURL use a proxy without adding options?

Tags: windows, command-line, proxy, curl

**Conclusion:** To correct, there's *no* problem in Windows version cURL. Besides, one should set `https_proxy` if they want to proxy HTTPS traffic (or better `all_proxy` if no need to set different proxies based on protocols).

I need cURL to access a website using proxy, as the site is restricted in my region. However, I may not be able to add `-x` option to the cURL commands (just suppose commands are executed by a closed-source application).

I have found that setting an environment variable like `http_proxy` can instruct cURL to use that proxy on Linux and macOS systems, but unfortunately it didn't work when I tried it on Windows `set http_proxy=http://localhost:port` `curl ...`, testing both the cURL shipped with Windows and the official release. I couldn't understand why this feature is missing on Windows. Are there alternative environment variables that have similar effects on Windows, or any build of cURL that is aware of the system proxy settings of Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I found later that those cURL commands accessed HTTPS URLs, so I should set `https_proxy` or `all_proxy` variable. I just misunderstood that HTTP-protocol proxy should be set as `http_proxy` (and maybe `socks5_proxy` etc. for other proxies ).